# MVC C# cerrar sesión y volver atrás

Tags: c#, mvc, login, model-view-controller

Bien, tengo un aplicativo en `MVC C#` en el cual el usuario se loguea. Luego viene una pantalla en la que ve sus cosas y tiene el botón de `cerrar sesión`. El botón para loguearse y desloguearse funciona pero el problema está en el botón **back** que cuando lo presiono se ve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego presiono `F5`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al presionar continuar se me vuelve a cargar la página del usuario logueado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, al volver atrás se ve esa página en blanco para el re-envío del formulario y al presionar **continuar** se vuelve a visualizar la vista del usuario. ¿Existe alguna forma de evitarlo? Actualmente mi código es este en el controlador:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
            return View();
        }

        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
        public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
            try
            {
                ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(psw);
                var usuario = sql.login(uname, psw);

                if (caracteres == "" || caracteres == null || caracteres.Equals(""))
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Ingrese contraseña.";
                }

                if (usuario.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.MensajeUsuario = "El usuario es inexistente.";
                }
                else if (usuario[0].nivel == 0
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 1
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 2
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 7)
                {
                    return View("Login1", usuario);
                }
                else if (usuario[0].nivel == 3
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 4
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 16)
                {
                    return View("Login2");
                }
                else 
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return View("");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Session.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        //return View("Index");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Y este es el código de la vista donde se encuentra el botón **cerrar sesión:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProvidusHomeWeb.Models.Usuarios>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Providus</title>
</head>
<body>

    @* Navigation Bar *@

    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="javascript:ruta()">Home</a>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Cerrar sesión</button>
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <label>Bienvenida/o:  @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.usuario)</label>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la vista del `index` donde se encuentra el form del `login:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script>
            //Script que impide el uso del botón atrás del navegador
            window.location.hash = "no-back-button";
            window.location.hash = "Again-No-back-button";
            window.onhashchange = function () { window.location.hash = ""; }
        </script>

    <title>Providus</title>

</head>
<body>

    @* Navigation Bar *@
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="javascript:ruta()">Home</a>
        <div class="login-container">
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="id01" class="modal">
        <form class="modal-content animate" onsubmit="return control()" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                <img src="~/Images/00.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Usuario:</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">

                <label for="psw"><b>Contraseña:</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." id="psw" name="psw" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)">

                <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <center><img class="img" src="~/Images/00.png" /></center>
    <center><p>Bienvenida/o, por favor inicie sesión.</p></center>

    <script>
        function control() {
            if (document.getElementById('uname').value == null
                || document.getElementById('uname').value == "") {
                alert("El campo no puede estar vacío.");
                document.getElementById('uname').focus();
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('psw').value == null || document.getElementById('psw').value == "") {
                alert("El campo no puede estar vacío.");
                document.getElementById('psw').focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>

    <center>
        <p>@ViewBag.Usu</p>
        <p>@ViewBag.Contra</p>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
```

Comment: El form de login, tiene el prevent.default?

Comment: Has probado a establecer el atributo `[Authorize] ` en tu método Index() del controlador Home? Eso debería habilitarte el redirigir a la página de Login al intentar acceder y no estar autenticado.

Comment: Si le pongo el `[Authorize]` me sale una página que dice que no tengo permisos para ver la página. Es decir, que ni siquiera puedo ver el `index` @SergioParraGuerra

Comment: Puede que sean las cookies de tu explorador?

puede que sea el explorador quien recuerde tu session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es más práctico deshabilitar las acción hacia atrás

```
    <script>
    //Script que impide el uso del botón atrás del navegador
    window.location.hash = "no-back-button";
    window.location.hash = "Again-No-back-button";
    window.onhashchange = function () { window.location.hash = ""; }

    </script>
```

Comment: Ya lo probé y no funciona.

Comment: Debes de agregarlo en la pagina de inicio, donde se logean los usuarios.

Comment: Ya lo hice y no ha funcionado.

Comment: Te comparto vídeo donde utilizo ese código
https://youtu.be/Pl8NaK6a3To

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme ajajaja he hecho como tú pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo por lo que creo que el problema es como está el controlador

Comment: XD
Proba con otro navegador, tal vez haya algo más que hacer para chrome

Comment: Conseguí inhabilitar el `back button` cambiando en el `LogOff` esto `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` por `return View("Index");` Con eso finalmente de desactivó el `back button` pero tengo una duda ¿Cómo lo solucionas si presionas el `back button` luego de que te logueaste? Es decir, a mi si me vuelve al `index`. ¿Cómo lo soluciono? ajaja Porque a eso ya no se como modificarlo en el controlador del `LogIn`

Comment: Supongo que usas un layout distinto para cuando se ha logeado el usuarip. Entonces en ese layout agregar las mismas líneas del javascripts

Comment: jajaja ya dejó de funcionar, es decir otra vez vuelve hacia atrás luego de cerrar sesión jkajaj. La web me odia

Comment: XD ja ja ja ja que terrible XD proba en otro navegador. En chrome hay algo más que hacer porque acabo de probar en chrome y ahí no me funciona

Comment: Maldita seas Chrome, maldito seas ajajaja

Comment: XD encontré está línea para que medio funcioné en chrome XD javascript:window.history.forward(1);  algo a nada. Lo puedes agregar al inicio de las otras líneas
Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Pues en firefox funciona de  maravilla pero en chrome no XD pero gracias igual ajaj

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo edita la respuesta y coloca los comentarios que hiciste como parte de tu respuesta, sino alguien que desee usarla tendria que leer comentarios para saber porque funciona o no.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve este problema en el pasado con `php`, pero la solución que encontré es general, así que espero lo puedas adaptar para MVC.

En primer lugar esto es una característica del navegador, por lo cual es un poco complejo de tratar.

En la respuesta anterior mencionan una solución en `javascript`, que igual intenté en su momento, pero la verdad no es optima ya que la pagina puede verse de igual manera por unos segundos hasta que se carga la etiqueta de `javascript` que ejecuta la acción, además si estás apretando el botón de volver atrás como un desquiciado igual podrás ver el contenido.
Otro problema que me encontré en el pasado para esa solución es que si deshabilitas la carga de `javascript` en el navegador y luego vuelves atrás igual podrás ver el contenido (A no ser que sea una SPA o aplicación similar que compruebe que javascript esté habilitado en el navegador).

La mejor solución que encontré en esos momentos fue limitar la carga de caché mediante headers aplicados en un middleware (DESDE EL BACK-END), esto puede hacer tu sitio más lento al no utilizar el cache, por lo cual debes utilizarlo solo en puntos estratégicos (Como el logout).

Los headers eran los siguientes (*basados en php*):

```
 header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
 header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
 header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

La solución en JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(history.forward(1)){
        location.replace( history.forward(1) );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Acabo de volver a probar los headers y funcionan a día de hoy.